# JQuery tabs displaying previous tab content

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click tab 2 it is displaying the content along with tab 1. I tried using prev() to hide the previous element. But it is hiding the whole tab menu and also active tab is not changing color. i have attached the jsfiddle link below
https://jsfiddle.net/nn9bqpsn/1/

```
<div class="Tabs">
  <ul>
     <li id="tab1" class="Active">Tab 1</li>
     <li id="tab2">Tab 2</li>
     <li id="tab3">Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab1-content" class="Tab" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
</div>

<div id="tab2-content" class="Tab" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
</div>

<div id="tab3-content" class="Tab" style="display:none">
  <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('li #tab1 .active')) {
        $('#tab1-content').show();
    }
});

$('#tab1').click(function () {
 $('#tab1-content').prev().hide();
    $('#tab1-content').show();
});

 $('#tab2').click(function () {
 $('#tab2-content').prev().hide();
    $('#tab2-content').show();

});

 $('#tab3').click(function () {
  $('#tab3-content').prev().hide();
    $('#tab3-content').show();

});
</script>
```

I have also tried with anchor tag with href but still not working. Attached below the jsfiddle for tabs using href https://jsfiddle.net/cL42g4sb/

Comment: Is there a reason the built in jqueryui tab does not work for you? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @Steve Here is the one I tried https://jsfiddle.net/0frr7qn2/2/.. but not working

Comment: the fiddle doesn't link the jqueryui library, is not formatted as per the API, and contains conflicting code from one of the answers below.  https://jsfiddle.net/midnight_sun/0frr7qn2/3/

Comment: But I need the content outside the tab header..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0frr7qn2/4/ working now.. but the color is not changing when the tabs are active..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of thousand solutions I took a longer route but hope it explains the functionality a little better.

Working jsFiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0frr7qn2/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //Hide all Tabs on laod
        $('.Tab').hide();

        //Check which tab is active
        var activeOnLoad = $('.Tabs ul li.Active').attr("id");
        $('#'+activeOnLoad+'-content').show();

        //Handle click event
        $('.Tabs ul li').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

          //Save clicked element to variable
           var clickedTab = $(this).attr("id");

          //Remove class from old tab
            $(this).parent().find('.Active').removeClass('Active');
          //Add Active class to clicked tab
            $(this).addClass('Active');

          //Hide all Tab elements
          $('.Tab').hide();

          //Show clicked Tab
          $('#'+clickedTab+'-content').show();
        });
    });
```

Update on OP's new code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                //Hide all Tabs on laod
        $('.Tab').hide();

        //Check which tab is active
        var activeOnLoad = $('.Tabs ul li a.Active').attr("href");
        $(activeOnLoad).show();

        //Handle click event
        $('.Tabs ul li a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

          //Save clicked element to variable
          var clickedTab = $(this).attr("href");

          //Remove class from old tab
            $(this).parents('ul').find('.Active').removeClass('Active');
          //Add Active class to clicked tab
            $(this).addClass('Active');

          //Hide all Tab elements
          $('.Tab').hide();

          //Show clicked Tab
          $(clickedTab).show();
        });
    });
```

jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmo2f1xp/)

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer.. But to make it more dynamic, I used  <li><a href="#tab1"  class="Active">Tab 1</a></li> ..So I used  var activeOnLoad = $('.Tabs > ul > li.active > a').attr("href") to get the href value.. But it is showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can hide elements with class "TAB" and then show the propper tab

```
...
    $('#tab1').click(function () {
        $('.Tab').hide();
        $('#tab1-content').show();
    });

    $('#tab2').click(function () {
        $('.Tab').hide();
        $('#tab2-content').show();

    });

    $('#tab3').click(function () {
        $('.Tab').hide();
        $('#tab3-content').show();

    });
....
```